# Run multiple sql files in mysql batch

Tags: mysql, batch-file

to run a single file you can run in mysql

> .\ filename

or you outside of mysql you can run

> mysql < filename

I have a directory of sql files so I'm trying to run them all at once by using a wildcard

> *.sql

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Assuming you're using bash:

`cat *.sql | mysql`

Comment: Awsome...worked: ) 

i used:

cat data*.sql | mysql -u root -p dbName

Comment: This will only work if all files end with semicolons after commands. Otherwise you'll get a SQL syntax error.

Comment: @StanJames Yep, I'm having the same problem!  Is there any way to fix that you can think of?  I suppose the other solution is to use a bash loop

Comment: To specify a location: cat *.sql | mysql --host=yourDatabaseIP --user=xxxxx --password=xxxxx -p databaseName.

Answer (score 12):

```
for %S in (*.sql) do mysql -u user_name database_name < %S
```

or

```
mysql -u user_name -p password database_name < file.sql
```

Comment: This works for me. The current version of mysql does not allow spaces between -u and username. The same applies for password as well.

Answer (score 11):

For Windows:

```
FOR %%A IN ("*.sql") DO "D:\mysql\Install\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql" --user=scooby --password=pwd123 databasename < %%A >output.tab
```

Comment: When running this in `cmd` (not powershell) I get an error `%%A was unexpected at this time.`

Answer (score 7):

bash:

```
mysql < <(cat *.sql)
```

Comment: i think someone marked this down because running this command gets an error "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Comment: That's because process substitution needs `bash`. Not `sh`, not `dash`, but `bash` proper. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Answer (score 7):

bash:

```
for sql_file in `ls /path/to/directory/*.sql`; do mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE < $sql_file ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat *.sql | mysql -u root -p "database name"
```

you can change root with your username and if you have password you can add your password behind -p

i hope this help