# bash console output print layout

Tags: bash, console, stdout

I want to make my writing to the console output in a nice tidy human readable.
here is how it looks now:

```
====================== Sat Apr 16 12:57:17 EDT 2022 ======================
==========================================================================
======================  Leopard - Download from S3  ======================
==========================================================================
==========================================================================
======================  Leopard - Decompressing  ======================
==========================================================================
total 1349872
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     12288 Apr 16 12:57 .
drwxrwxrwt. 4 root root       102 Apr 16 12:57 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 185070885 Apr 16 12:03 asdasdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  40344632 Apr 16 12:03 asdasdas.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     26631 Apr 16 12:03 asdad.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1679 Apr 16 12:03 asdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1237 Apr 16 12:03 asd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   5241900 Apr 16 12:03 asdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1144 Apr 16 12:03 asdasasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    489312 Apr 16 12:03 asdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1138 Apr 16 12:03 asdasdasd.sql.gz
==========================================================================
======================  NewYorkCity - Download from S3  ======================
==========================================================================
==========================================================================
======================  NewYorkCity - Unloading SSL Example  ======================
==========================================================================
total 1349872
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     12288 Apr 16 12:57 .
drwxrwxrwt. 4 root root       102 Apr 16 12:57 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 185070885 Apr 16 12:03 asdasdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  40344632 Apr 16 12:03 asdasdas.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     26631 Apr 16 12:03 asdad.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1679 Apr 16 12:03 asdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1237 Apr 16 12:03 asd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   5241900 Apr 16 12:03 asdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1144 Apr 16 12:03 asdasasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    489312 Apr 16 12:03 asdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1138 Apr 16 12:03 asdasdasd.sql.gz
```

I want that all the === line will be in the same length, and the text always in the center with 1 space on each side

Will appreciate assistance here :)

UPDATE / EDIT:
The original script is something like that:

```
eecho () { echo ==========================================================================; }

echo_stage () {
  START=1
  END=11
  for (( c=$START; c<=$END; c++ ))
  do
    printf == '-%.0s'
  done
  echo -n " " $1 " "
  for (( c=$START; c<=$END; c++ ))
  do
    printf == '-%.0s'
  done
  echo
}

stage() {
  eecho
  echo_stage "$1" "$2"
  eecho
}

print_date () { echo "======================" $(date) "======================"; }


reload_db() {
  print_date
  rm -rf /var/tmp/db
  mkdir -p /var/tmp/db
  stage "DB - Download from S3"
  aws s3 sync s3://db-backup/latest/ /var/tmp/db --profile=papilon --quiet
  stage "DB - Decompressing"
  pigz -d /var/tmp/db/*
  stage "DB - Restoring Data"
  cd /var/tmp/db
  stage "DB - Restoring Tables"
  for i in `ls -1 *.sql | grep -v "_view.sql"`;do echo $i;mysql db < $i;done
  stage "DB - Restoring Views"
  for i in `ls -1 *.sql | grep  "_view.sql"`;do echo $i;mysql db < $i;done
  stage "DB - Clean up"
  rm -rf /var/tmp/db
  print_date
}


reload_db
```

Comment: You can pipe through an awk or bash filter which can achieve this, however it would probably be better to modify the program generating this output, such that it accounts for the title length when printing the `===` either side.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have now posted your script, I will add a new answer for pure bash.

```
title() {
    local text pad

    (( ${#1} > 70 )) && { echo "$1"; return; }
    text=${1:+ }$1${1:+ }

    pad=$( eval "printf %.1s ={1..$(( ( 74 - ${#text} ) / 2 ))}" )

    echo "$pad$text$pad$( (( ${#text} % 2 )) && printf = )"
}
```

For `title 'foo bar'`, this function prints `foo bar` (or any string up to 70 characters) with a space either side, centered and padded to 74 columns with `=`. If the string is longer than 70 characters it's too long to pad, so it's printed as is.

```
================================ foo bar =================================
```

With no argument, or an empty argument, it prints a solid line of 74 `=`:

```
==========================================================================
```

- You can swap `=` for any single ASCII character.
- You can swap 74 for any even number. Also for an odd number, if you change `&& printf` to `|| printf` in the last line. (also change the `70` to N - 4)
- You can call `title` once for the date, or three times for the larger three line banners (see `banner` below).

**Explanation:**

- `${#text}` is bash for "length of `$text`".
- `${1:+ }` expands to a space, unless `$1` is empty or unset. This allows us to add spaces to either end of the string, or exclude them for an empty string.
- `={1..10}` expands to `=1 =2 =3 ... =10`, and `printf %.1s` prints the first character of each string. Combining these allows us to repeat a string (`=`) N times.
- But we can't use a variable (or arithmetic) in `{1..10}` normally. So we need `eval`.
- You probably heard `eval` is bad, and a security risk. That's often true, but here we are not passing any unknown data to `eval` (such as user input), and it's safe from code injection. (`${#text}` always expands to a single number)
- So we make two bars, of length (74 - text-length) / 2, adding another `=` to the second bar if the text length is an odd number.

I also made a few changes to your script which you might consider. Apart from the date and titles, these have nothing to do with the padding. The title and banner functions will work on your old script.

```
title() {
    local text pad

    (( ${#1} > 70 )) && { echo "$1"; return; }
    text="${1:+ }$1${1:+ }"

    pad=$( eval "printf %.1s ={1..$(( ( 74 - ${#text} ) / 2 ))}" )

    echo "$pad$text$pad$( (( ${#text} % 2 )) && printf = )"
}

banner() {
    title
    title "$1"
    title
}

reload_db() {

    local i

    title "$(date)"

    rm -rf /var/tmp/db || exit 1
    mkdir -p /var/tmp/db || exit 1

    banner 'DB - Download from S3'
    aws s3 sync s3://db-backup/latest/ /var/tmp/db --profile=papilon --quiet

    banner 'DB - Decompressing'
    pigz -d /var/tmp/db/*

    banner 'DB - Restoring Data'
    cd /var/tmp/db || exit 1

    banner 'DB - Restoring Tables'
    GLOBIGNORE='*_view.sql'
    for i in *.sql; do
        echo "$i"
        mysql db < "$i"
    done
   GLOBIGNORE=

    banner 'DB - Restoring Views'
    for i in *_view.sql; do
        echo "$i"
        mysql db < "$i"
    done

    banner 'DB - Clean up'
    rm -rf /var/tmp/db

    title "$(date)"
}
```

At the very least, you should exit early if `cd`, `mkdir`, or the first `rm` fail. Also, looping over an unquoted ls command sub is a [bad idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Instead you can use glob expansion (or `find`).

You could also concatenate the SQL scripts, but this only works if all the commands end with a semicolon (see [Run multiple sql files in mysql batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2458628/13919668)):

```
    big_title 'DB - Restoring Tables'
    GLOBIGNORE='*_view.sql'
    printf '%s\n' *.sql
    cat *.sql | mysql db
    GLOBIGNORE=

    big_title 'DB - Restoring Views'
    printf '%s\n' *_view.sql
    cat *_view.sql | mysql db
```

Answer (score 2):

This awk filter will size your `===` padding correctly, and align titles to the center, if you pipe your command output through it:

```
# cmd |

awk '
BEGIN {a[1] = "="}
NF>1 && $1~/^=+$/ && $NF~/^=+$/ {
    sub(/^=+/, "")
    sub(/=+$/, "")

    title_len=length($0)

    pad = ""
    for (i=1; i<=(74-title_len)/2; ++i) {
            pad=pad"="
    }

    $0 = pad $0 pad a[title_len%2]
}
1'
```

This doesn't wrap the `ls -l` output, only the titles. It assumes 74 is hardcoded as the length of the solid `===` lines (and doesn't change depending on terminal size). The array `a` is used to add an extra `=` when `74 - title_len` is an odd number.

Example output:

```
====================== Sat Apr 16 12:57:17 EDT 2022 ======================
==========================================================================
======================  Leopard - Download from S3  ======================
==========================================================================
==========================================================================
=======================  Leopard - Decompressing  ========================
==========================================================================
total 1349872
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     12288 Apr 16 12:57 .
drwxrwxrwt. 4 root root       102 Apr 16 12:57 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 185070885 Apr 16 12:03 asdasdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  40344632 Apr 16 12:03 asdasdas.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     26631 Apr 16 12:03 asdad.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1679 Apr 16 12:03 asdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1237 Apr 16 12:03 asd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   5241900 Apr 16 12:03 asdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1144 Apr 16 12:03 asdasasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    489312 Apr 16 12:03 asdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1138 Apr 16 12:03 asdasdasd.sql.gz
==========================================================================
====================  NewYorkCity - Download from S3  ====================
==========================================================================
==========================================================================
=================  NewYorkCity - Unloading SSL Example  ==================
==========================================================================
total 1349872
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     12288 Apr 16 12:57 .
drwxrwxrwt. 4 root root       102 Apr 16 12:57 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 185070885 Apr 16 12:03 asdasdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  40344632 Apr 16 12:03 asdasdas.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     26631 Apr 16 12:03 asdad.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1679 Apr 16 12:03 asdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1237 Apr 16 12:03 asd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   5241900 Apr 16 12:03 asdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1144 Apr 16 12:03 asdasasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    489312 Apr 16 12:03 asdasd.sql.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      1138 Apr 16 12:03 asdasdasd.sql.gz
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dan!
if i trigger my script by running "/root/script.sh" so i just need to do:

/root/script.sh |

awk '
BEGIN {a[1] = "="}
NF>1 && $1~/^=+$/ && $NF~/^=+$/ {
    sub(/^=+/, "")
    sub(/=+$/, "")

    title_len=length($0)

    pad = ""
    for (i=1; i<=(74-title_len)/2; ++i) {
            pad=pad"="
    }

    $0 = pad $0 pad a[title_len%2]
}
1'

I ask since it is not working.....

Comment: That's how it should be used. Your script might be printing to stderr, which doesn't go through the pipe. Try appending stderr to stdout, so it does: `/root/script.sh 2>&1 | awk '...'` (there's also `/root/script.sh |& awk '...'` to pipe _only_ stderr - requires bash >=4.0, otherwise `/root/script.sh 2 > >(awk '...')`). If you copy/paste your example output to file and run the file through my awk script you should get my example output.

Comment: Ideally, the padding should be done in the script that is creating the output. Apart from a quick fix, my answer was meant as much to be an example of how it can be done. If you post the original script, I may be able to provide an answer for modifying it, so it pads correctly.

Comment: Thanks again Dan. I Added the script as you asked.